# Wordpress so slow to load on MAMP

Tags: performance

My sites are so slow running on my local machine, with MAMP on Mac.

Any ideas of how to determine where the slow down is?

It's slower than making changes on my host!

Paul

Comment: Whats the overall database size for the site that is running slow?

Comment: IPv6 settings have been a culprit for me in the past. Also, you may like something like "VVV" for spinning up local WP environments.

Comment: Database is 3 meg.

Comment: It used to be fast - I don't want to have the hassle of setting up VVV. Rather work out why so slow to load on MAMP.

Answer (score 14):

Go to **wp-config.php**, find the line below:

```
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost:8889');
```

And change it to:

```
define('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1:8889');
```

Works like a charm!

Comment: Works! Thanks. I can't believe I was so lazy all these year, to never look into this. So many wasted seconds do add up.

Comment: This is great, I never knew about this!

Comment: Didn't worked for me...

Comment: Worked well for me! Why does this fix work?

Comment: Doesn't work with MAMP Pro. "No DB connection".

Answer (score 2):

If it's a Database problem you need to change it at `wp-config.php`.

You can choose :

```php
define( 'DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1:3306' );
```

(notice 3306 is your port number for DB make sure to change it as needed, but 3306 is a default for major softwares you also better change MAMP port to this, I've seen doing that making it faster too.)

---

or even better drop the TCP/IP completely.

```php
define( 'DB_HOST', 'localhost:/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock' );
```

Needless to say this option is more performant.